# contract invoke another contract function

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, parity

> - **Parity version**: 1.6.8
> - **Operating system**: MacOS
> - **And installed**: docker

---

start on

> --chain dev

here's test contract A

```
contract A {
    mapping (address => uint256) balances;
    function testFunc1(address _to, uint256 _value) {
        balances[_to] += _value;
    }
    function testFunc2(address _to, uint256 _value) {
        balances[_to] += 1;
        balances[_to] += 1;
    }
    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }
}
```

here's invoker contract B

```
contract B {
    function testSend1(address _contract, address _to, uint256 _value) {
        _contract.call.gas(400000)(bytes4(keccak256("testFunc1(address,uint256)")), _to, _value);
    }
    function testSend2(address _contract, address _to, uint256 _value) {
        _contract.call.gas(400000)(bytes4(keccak256("testFunc2(address,uint256)")), _to, _value);
    }
}
```

> - excute A's testFunc1 & testFunc2 is work
> - excute B's testSend1 is work
> - why excute B's testSend2 happened nothing ?【actually, the selected address should +2 on balances】

What's wrong with my contract code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh,I got it.

> contract_A_address.call

should to be:

> A a = A(contract_A_address);
>
> a.testFunc2(_to, _value);

Comment: Don't forget to mark your question accepted.